# Rails 3.0 Production Mode Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to put a rails 3.0 app in production mode. I'm hosting it on slicehost.com. I've set up ruby 1.8.7, updated my gems, installed rails 3.0, installed mysql, install passenger, and a blank rails app loads up. I've my yml file to connect to the db. I've even added RailsEnv production in my apache2 config (even though I'm told it defaults to production).

I then cd to my app run rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production and get the following error:

Could not find gem 'sqlite3'

Now, I am confused because I'm trying to create a production db in mysql, so why does it care about sqlite3.

It tells me to do a bundle install, but I could only guess this is going to set up a development db.

Any advice here.

I don't know what they did in rails 3.0, but this is really annoying.

I like how in 2.x you just add RAILS_ENV='production' in your environment file.

Any ways rant off.

I'd appreciate some help.

Thank you,

Brian

Update:

login as: root
root@ password:
Welcome to Ubuntu 11.04 (GNU/Linux 2.6.35.4-rscloud x86_64)

- Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
  You have mail.
  Last login: Tue Aug 23 14:15:09 2011 from adsl-99-142-52-152.dsl.emhril.sbcglobal.net
  root@:~# dir
  public_html  rvm-installer  sources
  root@:~# cd public_html
  root@:~/public_html# cd ticket
  root@:~/public_html/ticket# rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
  WARNING: This version of mysql2 (0.3.7) doesn't ship with the ActiveRecord adapter bundled anymore as it's now part of Rails 3.1
  WARNING: Please use the 0.2.x releases if you plan on using it in Rails <= 3.0.x
  rake aborted!
  !!! Missing the mysql2 gem. Add it to your Gemfile: gem 'mysql2'

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
root@:~/public_html/ticket#

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issue by using groups in your Gemfile.

Add sqlite to only to your test and development groups and in production run bundler as

```
bundle install --without test development
```

Sample Gemfile:

```
gem "mysql2", "~> 0.2.7
gem "passenger"

gem "sqlite3", :group => :development
```

Source: http://gembundler.com/groups.html

UPDATED: As of 0.3.0, and ActiveRecord 3.1 - the ActiveRecord adapter has been pulled out of mysql2 gem and into ActiveRecord itself. If you need to use mysql2 with Rails versions < 3.1 make sure and specify gem "mysql2", "~> 0.2.7" in your Gemfile

Comment: alright, added your code to my gem file and ran rake db:migrate rails_env=production and I got an error message. You can find the message in the update section of my post. Any ideas?

Comment: sorry, did the bundle install like you mentioned as well.

Comment: can you try `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate`

Comment: keeps telling me I'm missing the mysql2 gem

Comment: oops.. okay.. can you try changing the Gemfile entry to `gem "mysql2", "~> 0.2.7"`

Comment: yeah, I changed that still telling my to add mysql2 to my gem file

Comment: WOW. Figured out the problem. http://dalibornasevic.com/posts/19-runtimeerror-missing-the-mysql2-gem My adapter was supposed to be set to mysql2 in yml file.

Comment: can you check the adapter in database.yml. it should be `adapter: mysql2` instead of mysql